# ExecuterService and Writing to File

Tags: java, file-io, threadpool

I am trying to use `ExecutorService` in order to write to a file. However, when I execute this code, the execution goes to `outFile.close();` before the execution is completed, which throws

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

How can I call `outFile.close()` only after all the task has been completed?

(PS: I have removed all try/catch blocks for code clarity.)

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  final int counter = i;
  executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      outFile.write(wld.getWord(counter) + "successful");
      outFile.write("\n");
    }               
  });
}

outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud first wait for all the tasks to finish. Once you've submitted all the jobs, you may invoke `executor.shutdown()` and wait for all threads to finish using `executor.awaitTermination()`.

Here's an example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      final int counter = i;
      executor.execute(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              outFile.write(wld.getWord(counter) + "successful");
              outFile.write("\n");
          }               
      });
}

executor.shutdown(); //shut down executor
executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //waiting for 60 seconds

outFile.close(); //and then you may safely close the stream knowing that all the tasks have finished
```

Note: the main thread may wake up before all the jobs are finished, because of the timeout. You may increase that time or wait in a loop until `isTerminated()` condition is met:

```java
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. However, I calculated the execution of time with and without executer service and I don't feel any difference.

Should I not see improved execution when using ExecutorService?

Comment: You will hardly notice any performance improvement in this case, because writing speed is limited by IO and OS features.